# Custom delegate Paint persist when editing

Tags: c++, qt, model, delegates

I am trying to write custom delegate and custom model as a part of learning Qt.

I made a simple custom model based on `QAbstractTableModel`. I did not do anything complicated. It only generates the data in its constructor as well as minimally implement the pure virtual function.

I made a custom delegate which display numerical data in terms of bars. I also implemented a spin box as an editor to edit data.

The program works well. I can view, edit and modify data through a `QTableView` with the delegate set.

But there is a small problem. When I call the editor, the data bar persists, which means I see the data bar at the background and the spin box on top.

Initially, I think it is because the `Qt::EditRole` in the `QAbstractTableModel::data()` has not been set properly. But, surprisingly, I find that the `Qt::EditRole` has never been called.

So, there are two question:

1. How to remove the data bar when I am having the spin box editor?
2. Why is the `EditRole` never been called in my custom model?

Here is part of my code:

My Custom Model:

```
MyModel::MyModel(QObject* parent):QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        localData.push_back(i*i);
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch(role)
    {
    case Qt::EditRole:
        qDebug() << "EditRole"; //Never Print Out
        return 0;

    case Qt::DisplayRole :
        if (index.column() == 0)
            return (index.row());

        if (index.column() == 1)
            return (localData.at(index.row()));
    default:
        return QVariant();
    }
}
```

My Custom Delegate:

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    painter->save();
    painter->setPen(Qt::red);
    painter->setBrush(Qt::red);

    double factor = 0;
    if (index.data().toDouble() > 100)
        factor = 1;
    else
        factor = index.data().toDouble() / (double) (100.0);

    painter->drawRect(option.rect.x()+5, option.rect.y()+3, (option.rect.width()-10)*factor, option.rect.height()-6);
    painter->restore();
}

QWidget* MyDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QSpinBox* box = new QSpinBox(parent);
    box->setMinimum(0);
    box->setMaximum(100);
    return box;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to set setAutoFillBackground(true) for your view
2. Editrole is not called because your custom editor does not query the model for that data. You don not set any value for your spin box. Try to set it as:

   ```
   box->setValue(model.data(Qt::EditRole));
   ```

in the MyDelegate::createEditor() function.

Comment: Did you set auto fill background property for view or for the editor (spin box)?

Comment: It is strange that now the background is removed when I enter the "Editing Mode". I did not do anything to the code. But I move the project from an ubuntu platform to a windows platform. I will try it under ubuntu again tomorrow. Will give update.

Comment: I confirm that it is platform related issue. With the same code, under Windows environment, my program can clear the background at "Editing Mode", while it cannot under Ubuntu.